# Slide Segue in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm trying to create a horizontally sliding segue that'll pan from one view to the next. I have the panning down, but it shows a black space in the area being revealed where it should be showing the next view controller. This is how I'm implementing my segue

```
class SlideSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    enum Direction {
        case Left
        case Right
    }

    // MARK: - Properties
    var direction = Direction.Left

    // MARK: -
    override func perform() {
        let srcVc = self.sourceViewController
        let destVc = self.destinationViewController


        let destView = destVc.view.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(true)
        var frame = destView.frame
        frame.origin.x = CGFloat(valForDirection()) * srcVc.view.frame.width
        destView.frame = frame
        srcVc.view.addSubview(destView)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
            let x = CGFloat(self.valForDirection()) * srcVc.view.bounds.width
            let slide = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(x, 0)
            srcVc.view.transform = slide
            }) { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
                srcVc.presentViewController(destVc, animated: false, completion: nil)

                destView.removeFromSuperview()
        }

    }

    func valForDirection() -> Int {
        return direction == Direction.Left ? -1 : 1
    }

}

class SlideLeftSegue: SlideSegue {
    override func perform() {
        self.direction = Direction.Left
        super.perform()
    }
}

class SlideRightSegue: SlideSegue {
    override func perform() {
        self.direction = Direction.Right
        super.perform()
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

[image]

**EDIT (SOLVED)**
This is the final working solution thanks the two answers below

```
class SlideSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    enum Direction: Int {
        case Left = 1
        case Right = -1
    }

    // MARK: - Properties
    var direction = Direction.Left

    // MARK: -
    override func perform() {
        let srcVc = self.sourceViewController
        let destVc = self.destinationViewController


        let destView = destVc.view.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(true)
        var frame = destView.frame
        frame.origin.x = CGFloat(direction.rawValue) * srcVc.view.frame.width
        destView.frame = frame
        srcVc.view.addSubview(destView)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
            let x = -CGFloat(self.direction.rawValue) * srcVc.view.bounds.width
            let slide = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(x, 0)
            srcVc.view.transform = slide
            }) { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
                srcVc.presentViewController(destVc, animated: false, completion: nil)

                destView.removeFromSuperview()
        }

    }

}

class SlideLeftSegue: SlideSegue {
    override func perform() {
        self.direction = Direction.Left
        super.perform()
    }
}

class SlideRightSegue: SlideSegue {
    override func perform() {
        self.direction = Direction.Right
        super.perform()
    }
}
```

Comment: I've test your code ,when I reverse the frame's original's setup it work correctly.

Comment: @MatthewLuiHK What do you mean by reverse the setup?

Comment: I've added an answer to it, please try.

Comment: Or you can use SWReveal. It made with Obj-C, but you can use bridging to connect the library for swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I test with the following modification, and it work well.

```
func valForDirection() -> Int {
    return direction == Direction.Left ? 1 : -1
}
```

If sliding to left, the destView's originX should be it's width. else -width.

Comment: This almost works for me. I made one modification and it works now! I need to negate the new x value that is used for the slide animation and it works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your `SlideSegue` class to this, removing the `valForDirection` function (I have taken the liberty to refactor it a little, if you don't mind)

```
class FirstCustomSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    enum Direction: Int {
        case Left = 1
        case Right = -1
    }

    // MARK: - Properties
    var direction = Direction.Left

    // MARK: - Perform
    override func perform() {
        let srcVc = self.sourceViewController
        let destVc = self.destinationViewController

        destVc.view.frame = srcVc.view.frame
        destVc.view.frame.origin.x = CGFloat(direction.rawValue) * srcVc.view.frame.width
        let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
        window?.insertSubview(destVc.view, aboveSubview: srcVc.view)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
            let x = CGFloat(self.direction.rawValue) * srcVc.view.bounds.width
            destVc.view.frame.origin.x = 0
            srcVc.view.frame.origin.x = -x

            }) { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
                srcVc.presentViewController(destVc, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
    }

}
```

I haven't tested this yet, so I'm not 100% sure that the syntax is correct.

**UPDATE**: MatthewLuiHK seems to be right. All you have to do is flip around the values.

Credits: http://www.appcoda.com/custom-segue-animations/

Comment: I updated the syntax to be correct. I like the enum over the function, much cleaner. Unfortunately this had the same problem :/

Comment: @Chris huh... does it work when you do a regular segue?

Comment: @Chris wait I might have figured it out. I'll just update my answer.

Comment: @Chris I think the problem was that you weren't moving the `destVc` during the animation. I have updated my answer, so do tell me if it works.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried it, but it's the same animation with the same result

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me, it reveals the new view controller from beneath the VC being swiped away, however when the segue is complete the view controller briefly flashes black.

Any ideas how to ensure a smooth transition every time?

```
import UIKit

class SlideSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

enum Direction: Int {
    case Left = 1
    case Right = -1
}

// MARK: - Properties
var direction = Direction.Left

// MARK: -
override func perform() {
    let srcVc = self.sourceViewController
    let destVc = self.destinationViewController


    let destView = destVc.view.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(true)
    var frame = destView.frame
    frame.origin.x = CGFloat(direction.rawValue) * srcVc.view.frame.width
    destView.frame = frame
    srcVc.view.addSubview(destView)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
        let x = -CGFloat(self.direction.rawValue) * srcVc.view.bounds.width
        let slide = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(x, 0)
        srcVc.view.transform = slide
        }) { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
            srcVc.presentViewController(destVc, animated: false, completion: nil)

            destView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
}

class SlideLeftSegue: SlideSegue {
override func perform() {
    self.direction = Direction.Left
    super.perform()
}
}

class SlideRightSegue: SlideSegue {
override func perform() {
    self.direction = Direction.Right
    super.perform()
}
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: I'm still having the issue with the flash at the end. And I've noticed, if you create a navigation stack that doesn't involve dismissing VCs, the stack gets overloaded with replicator views, I think `_UIReplicatorView`. You can see this if you use the UI inspector tool in Xcode